# php mysql error Undefined offset: 0

Tags: php, mysql, undefined, offset

I am getting  this error message " Undefined offset: 0 " . what is the reason and How can it be solved??
here is my code:

```
<?php            
    $rows= mysqli_query ( $con,"SELECT COUNT(Mobile) AS count  FROM data Where Blood = '$bloodGroup'" );
    $count = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $rows  ) ;
    $count = $count[0]['count']; 
?>
```

Comment: `$count = $count['count']`

Comment: Learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think mysqli_fetch_assoc return single array without index so you can use like this:

```
<?php            
    $rows= mysqli_query ( $con,"SELECT COUNT(Mobile) AS count  FROM data Where Blood = '$bloodGroup'" );
    $count = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $rows  ) ;
    $count = $count['count']; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_fetch_assoc()` doesn't return a multi-dimensional array. It returns an array containing one row of results.

```
$count = $count['count'];
```

Your code would be correct if you used `mysqli_fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)` instead of `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`

Answer (score 0):

Try to update:

```
<?php            
    $rows = mysqli_query ( $con,"SELECT COUNT(Mobile) AS count  FROM data Where Blood = '$bloodGroup'" );
    $count = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $rows  ) ;
    $count = $count["count"];
?>
```

Comment: There's no `Mobile` column in the results.

Comment: Sorry, now i have updated code..

Answer (score -3):

//try this

```
$count = isset($count[0]['count']) ? $count[0]['count'] : 0;
```

Comment: There will never be `$count[0]`.